# In math, round down or round up

Tags: word-choice, mathematics

In math a number can be 'rounded' (sounds strange) up or down. For example if I want to round up to the next whole number (the 2.4 gets 3).

How do I express in English that I always want to round down or up.

```
"Always round down"
"Always round up"
```

Or is rounding named/expressed different in English?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! And it's round up. I can't imagine any other question you might have asked.

Comment: "Always round up" is fine, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer) mentions a couple more formal options, too: _round away from zero_ and _round toward infinity_.

Comment: This is probably more 'jargon-y' than you're looking for, but "always round down" could be replaced with `floor` and "always round up" could be replaced with `ceil` (which stands for the "ceiling" function).  As another commenter said, these are technical words associated with programming, and not something you'd use in casual conversation.

Comment: Another equivalent of "always round down" is 'truncate.'  When you *truncate* a decimal, you just "chop off" all the digits after the decimal point - so 2.987 *truncates* to 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase you're looking for is "round off".

"Round off" means "round down or up, whichever is appropriate".

Comment: Isn't "round up" correct too? Or is it about rounded numbers to larger or smaller?

Comment: "Round up" means "round to the next higher number".  "Round down" means "round to the next lower number".  "Round off" means "do whichever of 'round up' or 'round down' is correct."  I do *occasionally* see "round up" used to mean "round off", but that's ambiguous.

Comment: Rounding up: 4.7 to 5.  Rounding down: 4.2 to 4.  Rounding off: either of these.

Comment: Ok. So saying "Always round up" (4.4 -> 5), "Always round down" (4.6 -> 4), "Always round off" (4.4 -> 4; 4.6 -> 5) is correct, right? (want to add that to a UI but I was unsure how to name the labels).

Comment: I get it now. +1!

Comment: Yup!  That's correct.

Comment: Agree with all StephenD. has said.  As an aside, many programming languages use "floor" and "ceiling" to refer to rounding down and rounding up.  [e.g. `floor(3.01) = 3, floor(3.99) = 3, ceiling(3.01) = 4 , ceiling(3.99 = 4)` ]

Comment: This shouldn't be the 'correct' answer - in coding, 'round off' means nothing - it's ambiguous to a BrE ear anyway, as it is more likely to refer to smoothing wood than maths. Rounding is up or down, floor or ceiling. The true answer isn't 'English' but it is 'coding' which has its own language.

Comment: @tetsujin - OP didn't .  In AmE, we definitely use "round off" in common speech to indicate "round." Perhaps Stephen Dunscombe could add a geographical context to his answer...... **Q** _Do you want the exact cost estimate?_  **A** _Nah - just round it off._  (How would you respond in BrE?)

Comment: @Adam - "Just round it off" won't necessarily result in always rounding up. Using the example in the O.P.'s question, let's say I buy you a loaf of bread that costs $2.40, and you want to pay me back. I ask, "Do you want to know the exact cost?" You reply, "Nah - just round it off." In that case, I might very well round _down_, and say, "It was about two bucks," but the O.P. is looking for a prompt that would lead me to say _three_, not _two_.

Comment: @J.R. Agree on the meaning. - I was responding to Tetsujin who said _"This shouldn't be the 'correct' answer - in coding, 'round off' means nothing"_   I wanted to reaffirm that at least in the U.S., _"Round off" means "round down or up, whichever is appropriate"._   While he may not have answered the OP's question, StephenD did give true information (at least for AmE)